# I want to print a website and exclude the footer from first page

Tags: css, pdf, footer, display

I have a website and want to generate a pdf with the print function. I need to add a footer on all pages.
Only the first page should be without the footer. I already tried the display property which doesn`t work. Do you know a solution?

This is how the footer is set:

````
.page-footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
// HTML
<footer class="page-footer">
    Text for footer
</footer>```
````

Answer (score 0):

Add another class to home page footer and hide it on print CSS. Along with page-footer class add another class home-page-footer and hide it when printing.

```
.home-page-footer { display: none; }
```

You will have to create separate print.css and set css rule for print media

print.css

```
@page {
   /* rules as per your requirement */
  size: 190mm 130mm;
  margin: 0;
  margin-top:10mm;
}
@media print {

  .home-page-footer { display: none; }
  
  }
```

You don't need to set rule for .home-page-footer class in your normal css file. or condition.

Comment: I guess the problem is that the footer they have should not get printed on the first page but on every other page. So your solution will not help?

Comment: Do you have control over this website or this website of owned by someone else? Can you update this css?

Comment: It's my website

Comment: Fine, then can you add class home-page-footer only to home page footer? along with default footer.

Comment: <footer class="home-page-footer page-footer">
         Text for footer
     </footer>  only for home page